# How to add note annotation on page of PDFView

Tags: ios, cocoa, pdfkit

I am trying to add note (Bubble text) annotation on PDF page using following code but it is not working for me.

```
        let rect = CGRect.init(x: 300, y: 300, width: 50, height: 50)

        let ann = PDFAnnotation.init(bounds: rect, forType: .text, withProperties: nil)
        ann.iconType = .note
        ann.caption = "Test Comments"
        self.currentPage?.addAnnotation(selectedAnnotation!)
```

I have also tried to find solution on various blogs but there is very little information available out there.

Can anyone please suggest what is issue with above code.